# How to compare two instances of System.Text.Encoding in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, unicode

I have two instances of System.Text.Encoding.  I'd like to be able to compare them to see if they represent the same code page. (Actually it's a bit more specific - one of the instances is UTF8, and I want to see if the unknown encoding is UTF8.)

In .NET, I can just query [the CodePage property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.codepage%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on the Encoding type.  [This isn't available in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

What's an effective way of comparing them?  Use ToString() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are not aware, the WebName property returns essentially the same information: it returns "utf-8" if the encoding is UTF-8.